# How to group a section of numbers in a list together Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am currently working on a program in which I must take a string as input and then reverse all of the numbers in that string, leaving all other characters the same. I managed to do this, however it seems that I must reverse sections of numbers at a time, and not reverse every number. I am not sure how I can do this with my solution. I would prefer not to use any libraries.

For example:

> For input abc123abc456abc7891
>
> My result: abc198abc765abc4321
>
> Target Result: abc321abc654abc1987

Here is what I have:

```
#Fucntion just reverses the numbers that getn gives to it
def reverse(t):
    t = t[::-1]
    return t

def getn(w):
    w = list(w)
    Li = []
#Going through each character of w(the inputted string) and adding any numbers to the list Li
    for i in w:
        if i.isdigit():
            Li.append(i)
#Turn Li back into a string so I can then reverse it using the above function
#after reversing, I turn it back into a list
    Li = ''.join(Li)
    Li = reverse(Li)
    Li = list(Li)
#I use t only for the purpose of the for loop below,
#to get the len of the string,
#a is used to increment the position in Li
    t = ''.join(w)
    a = 0
#This goes through each position of the string again,
#and replaces each of the original numbers with the reversed sequence
    for i in range(0,len(t)):
        if w[i].isdigit():
            w[i] = Li[a]
            a+=1
#Turn w back into a string to print
    w = ''.join(w)
    print('New String:\n'+w)

x = input('Enter String:\n')
getn(x)
```

Comment: In general you merely need to interleave your digit-finding and reversal.  Find a contiguous string of digits -- and when you hit the end, stop there, reverse the digits, and *then* go on.

Comment: @Prune I tried adding comments to make it easier to understand my code. And that is what I am attempting to do, I am just not sure how to implement that here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution outline:

- Break the string into a list of substrings.  Each substring is defined by the division between digits and non-digits.  Your result at othe end of this stage should be `["abc", "123", "abc", "456", "abc", "7891"]`
- Go through this list; replace each digit string with its reverse.
- `join` this list into a single string.

The final step is simply `''.join(substring_list)`.

The middle step is contained in what you're already doing.

The first step isn't trivial, but well within the coding ability in your original post.

Can you take it from here?

---

UPDATE

Here's the logic to break the string into groups as needed.
Check the "digit-ness" of each char.  If it's different from that of the previous char, then you have to start a new substring.

```
instr = "abc123abc456abc7891"

substr = ""
sub_list = []
prev_digit = instr[0].isdigit()

for char in instr:
    # if the character's digit-ness is different from the last one,
    #    then "tie off" the current substring and start a new one.
    this_digit = char.isdigit()
    if this_digit != prev_digit:
        sub_list.append(substr)
        substr = ""
        prev_digit = this_digit

    substr += char

# Add the last substr to the list
sub_list.append(substr)

print(sub_list)
```

Output:

```
['abc', '123', 'abc', '456', 'abc', '7891']
```

Comment: I will certainly try, thank you for guiding me in the right direction rather than just giving me code, I am sure it will help me in the long run.

Comment: Okay, so I have been attempting to create a solution to split the string into subsections for the past hour, but I can't seem to figure it out. I was doing something along the line of "for letter in range 0 to length of string, if the letter is a digit and the next letter is a letter, split." However I am getting errors and I can't seem to think of a logical solution to do this. If there is anything more you add to this part, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you for the explanation of the first part in addition to what I needed to do

Answer (score 3):

The following isn't particularly elegant, but is conceptually fairly simple, using `groupby` from `itertools` to split the string up into the groups of digits or non-digits (this is Python 3.7, I think it should work on any Python 3.x but haven't tested except on 3.7):

```
from itertools import groupby

def getn(s):
    sections = groupby(s, key=lambda char: char.isdigit())
    result = []
    for isdig, chars in sections:
        if isdig:
            result += list(reversed(list(chars)))
        else:
            result += list(chars)
    return "".join(result)

input = "abc123abc456abc7891"
print(getn(input))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, however I was hoping I could accomplish this without using any libraries, as it is an assignment and I don't believe I am allowed to use them here.

Comment: OK, fair enough - that wasn't clear in your question

Comment: Sorry about that, I will try to make that more clear in my post, thank you again for your response though!

Answer (score 2):

This is a working code based on [@prune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55132370/11021851) suggestion.

```py
def type_changed(s1,s2):
    if s1.isdigit() != s2.isdigit():
        return True

def get_subs(s):
    sub_strings = list()
    i = 0
    start = i
    while i < len(s):
        if i == len(s)-1:
            sub_strings.append(s[start:i+1])
            break
        if type_changed(s[i], s[i+1]):
            sub_strings.append(s[start:i+1])
            start = i+1
        i +=1
    return sub_strings

def reverse(subs):
    for i, sub in enumerate(subs):
        if sub.isdigit():
            subs[i] = subs[i][::-1]
    return ''.join(subs)


test_strings = [
    'abc123abc456abc7891b',
    'abc123abc456abc7891',
    'abc123abc456abc7891abc',
    'a1b2c3d4e5f6',
    'a1b2c3d4e5f6g',
    '1234',
    'abcd',
    '1',
    'a'
]

for item in test_strings:
    print(item)
    print(reverse(get_subs(item)))
    print
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to separate numbers and letters into substring sections. Iterate through each section and reverse only the integer sections. Then join the sections into a single string.

```
def getn(w):
   ans = []
   section = ''

   if w[0].isdigit():
       last = 'digit'
   else:
       last = 'letter'

   for char in w:
       if char.isdigit():
           if last == 'letter':
               ans.append(section)
               section = ''
               last = 'digit'
           section += char
       else:
           if last == 'digit':
               ans.append(section)
               section = ''
               last = 'letter'
           section += char
   ans.append(section)

   for index, section in enumerate(ans):
       if section.isdigit():
           ans[index] = section[::-1]
   return ''.join(ans)

string = 'abc123abc456abc7891'
print(getn(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

using regex substitute function

```
import re

instr = "abc123abc456abc7891"

result = re.sub('\d+', lambda x : ''.join(reversed(str(x[0]))), instr)

print(result)

"abc321abc654abc1987"
```